# Why does Xubuntu not shutdown, it just goes to the log in screen

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 and when I try to shut down or restart via the GUI, it just goes to the login screen. I know a lot of people seem to have a similar problem, but usually they can shut down once they reach the login screen. I cannot, instead all the options to shutdown, sleep, etc. are grayed out. Shutting down and restarting via the command line works fine.

I've tried to edit my xinitrc file by adding the line `ck-launch-session startxfce4`
which seems to be a fix for some people, but no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I've been messing with the files in /etc/pam.d in order to connect the xubuntu system to a domain and I had overwritten the information in /etc/pam.d/common-session. Once I put the default information back in, it allowed me to shut down through the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem, and I believe the issue was a configuration issue with lightdm.  Unfortunately, uninstalling lightdm does not remove all the configuration files.

I recommend trying to remove all the lightdm.conf files, and any file with that in its name, and then reinstalling lightdm

What I'm suggesting is risky!  If lightdm get's messed up, you won't be able to get back into a gui.  So I suggest this order:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm` once, just to make sure it will work.

Then, delete files and folders found by `locate lightdm.conf` that are in `/etc` and `/usr`.  NOT what is in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`

Lastly, `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm` for real

While I did experience this issue, I ended up solving it with a clean install, since I was experiencing other bugs as well.  So, I can't vouch for this solution.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known issue, just follow the instructions on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792/comments/24

Good Luck.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Link-only answers are of low quality and might be deleted. Please consider expanding it.